# Find name of process id after reboot (from previous boot)

Tags: process

If I have a pid from a previous boot, how can I find the name of the process with pid on the currently running system?

Comment: You can't. PID's are assigned dynamically when processes are started and restarted, so you need to identify the process while it's running.

Comment: Yes, that's whay I guessed, is there any "logging" facility maybe?

Comment: The syslog will have the PID in square brackets after the process name - if the process wrote anything to the syslog. For instance, all `systemd` entries will have `systemd[1]`, because systemd is PID 1.

Comment: Ah, it says "kernel: pid=1234".